# DLL Hell with Entity Framework and Lucene

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project that I need to update to use Lucene 3.0. I needed to manually set the framework to use .NET Framework 4.5 because I'm using the latest Windows Azure libraries which require this version. Everything is working, except when I add a new data model with the Entity Framework. I can successfully add a new data model with the Entity Framework. However, when I attempt to execute a basic stored procedure (it only executes a query), I get a runtime exception. The exception is:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

When I look at the LoaderExceptions property, I see the following:

```
[0] {"Could not load file or assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85089178b9ac3181' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85089178b9ac3181"}  System.Exception {System.IO.FileLoadException}

[1] {"Could not load file or assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85089178b9ac3181' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85089178b9ac3181"}  System.Exception {System.IO.FileLoadException}
```

The oddity is, I can't find a single reference to Lucene.Net version 2.9.4.1 anywhere. I do reference the 3.0.3.0 version of Lucene.Net in my app. Can someone tell me where the 2.9.4.1 version of the file would be referenced? I've looked in the following locations:

```
MyProject.csproj 
Web.config
Global.asax.cs
packages.config
```

How do I fix this? I've been beating my head on this for 2 days. Its so bizarre. Thank you so much for any help that can be provided.

Comment: I assume you've already done a clean and rebuild all?

Comment: Are you sure the dll you reference and the dll on your system are of the same version? Also a clean build can help.

Comment: I have done a clean and rebuild all. Also, I'm experiencing this issue in my local environment. I have not deployed it to a production environment yet.

Answer (score 1):

I know not exactly an answer to the question, but if it truely does stump you (and you're lucky enough that the two versions are compatibly) you can redirect any requests for 2.9.4.1 to the version you do have by adding a binding redirect to your config file.

see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433ysdt1.aspx